# How would I replace a part of a string that contains unknown values

Tags: c#, string, replace

So i want to replace some a part of a text file knowing only that it looks like this:

```
Part "name" {11.015586 1.208383 -5.521754 0.001870 -0.975887 0.218267 0xffffffff 0.133086 0.811246 0.000000 1.000000}
```

name would be inputted from terminal and inside of brackets would have hundreds of lines of values as well as other brackets inside it. Also the word Part would have a tab before it, there would be a new line after the first { before last one there also would be a new line and a tab. How would I go about replacing the part inside the brackets or even all of it with another string.

Comment: Would that also be an unknown string? Then the answer is simple, but yet unknown. (Please share more details which are known).

Comment: Please make your question in an [mre]. Post complete working C# code, and expected output.

Comment: the file would be full of similar parts

Comment: Yes, and my car is blue, go and wash it, it is outside........  After this statement you still do not KNOW which car to wash, do you ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```
            string unknownPieceOfText = "Part \"name\" {11.015586 1.208383 -5.521754 0.001870 -0.975887 0.218267 0xffffffff 0.133086 0.811246 0.000000 1.000000}";
            string anotherString = "another string";

            int OpeningAccolade = unknownPieceOfText.IndexOf('{');
            int ClosingAccolade = unknownPieceOfText.IndexOf('}');

            string newString = unknownPieceOfText.Substring(0, OpeningAccolade + 1) + anotherString + unknownPieceOfText.Substring(ClosingAccolade);

            Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

It outputs: `Part "name" {another string}`

But we do not know if there are more '{' or '}' inside that text. Especially more '}' will make this solution worthless...  (and it already has not much value)